# Ctrl+D in bash shows unexpected result inside a C program

Tags: c

I am learning c programming using [this tutorial on building your own lisp](https://buildyourownlisp.com).

Right now I am in chapter 4 where they make an interactive prompt. I did the first step to make a program that does print out user input repeatedly.

Here is the code for that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static char input[2048];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  puts("Went Version 0.0.0.0.1");
  puts("Press Ctrl+c to Exit\n");
  while(1){
    fputs("went> ", stdout);
    fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
    printf("%s", input);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And it worked as expected

```
~$ ./main
Went Version 0.0.0.0.1
Press Ctrl+c to Exit

went> hello
hello
went>
```

But when I tried to end it with Ctrl+d instead of Ctrl+c it does something weird.

```
went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went> went>^C
```

It runs like this until I kill it with Ctrl+C.

It's not an issue or something, just curious to know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what basically happens here:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> triggers an end of file on `stdin`. After that, all attemps to read from `stdin` will result in `fgets` returning `NULL` (and `feof(stdin)` returning `true`, which is not relevant here).

As you don't check anything in your loop, there is no reason your loop stops. This is what happens:

1. you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which triggers an end of file
2. you read from `stdin` with `fgets` which now returns `NULL` and leaves the `input` buffer unchanged.
3. you dispay the content of the `input` buffer
4. you goto 2 etc.

This has nothing to do with bash.

You need to check for the EOF (end of file) condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char input[2048];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  puts("Went Version 0.0.0.0.1");
  puts("Press Ctrl+c to Exit\n");
  while(1){
    fputs("went> ", stdout);

    if (fgets(input, 2048, stdin) == NULL)  // change here
      break;                                //

    printf("%s", input);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Telling beginners about `feof(stdin)` is probably counter-productive. They are likely to misuse this confusing function.

Comment: @chqrlie confusing? The second and third sentence in the [feof documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) explains it clearly. `scanf`, OTOH, is what I'd call a confusion function.

Comment: `feof()` is not intrinsically confusing, but the semantics are non-intuitive and it is a fact that beginners misuse it, as they do `strncpy`, `strtok` and `scanf` too.

Comment: “After that, nothing can be read from `stdin`” is incorrect. With an input stream from a terminal, the EOF indicator can be reset and further data can be read. Pressing control-D does not actually cause an EOF in the “file” associated with the stream; a soft EOF is generated within the stream software.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for the comment. I've rephrased the answer.